# How to get center of a QscrollArea

Tags: qt

I created a QScrollArea with a QLabel that contains a QPixmap.
And I know the QPixmap size.

I would like to know the center of the area displayed.

But I can't find any function in QScrollArea that can return the center. 
Any idea how to do it? Should I calculate it with the proportion of srollbar? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you need: center of the viewport or center of the containing widget? In both cases it simply can be calculated.

Comment: @vahancho Thanks for your comment. I don't know what should I call it. As I said, the center of area displayed. For instance, there is an image 400*400. The QScrollArea is zooming on a square (0,0) (100,100). I want to get the center (50,50) of the displayed area.

Comment: QRect has a center function. Do you have the zoom QRect?

Comment: @cppguy Thank you for your comment. I don't know hot to get the QRect of the zoom. In fact, the zoom can be changed. As a viewer window.

Comment: Does the `viewport()->rect().center()` give you the coordinates of the center?